# Mulesoft Anypoint 7 . MYSQL missing MySQL driver class

Tags: java, mysql, maven, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

It's a fundamental question but it's a really annoying issue when starting with mule

> Error: "Cannot load class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'". Caused by:
> java.sql.SQLException: Error trying to load driver:
> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver : Cannot load class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver': [
> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, Cannot load class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver': [
> Class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
> blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla

That is very likely because I don't have the mysql connector jar as a pom dependency.
But when I added it to the pom file, the error persisted and I could not find the way to force a dependencies update.

I added manually the library inside classpath but still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is remove ALL library or reference to a MySQL connector inside the proyect.

So, when you go to setup your connection, will find something like next image:

[image: Mulesoft Enypoint 7 new Database Config]

Configure->Add maven Dependency

This new windows has been open and you only need to place the right mysql version:

[image: Mulesoft Anypoint 7 - Setting up mysql Driver in the only way it works]

After that, just setup your connection and voilá!

[image: Mulesoft Anypoint 7 - Database config]

Curiosly, instead of a Success Connection Test, the error persists when the next flow component (Transform Message) tries to update metadata

[image: MuleSoft Anypoint 7 - Mysql Connector fails]

After one hour I restarted the IDE and Magic happens!
It's working.